# $G$ is solvable and $N \unlhd G$. Prove: $G/N$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a solvable group and let $N \unlhd G$. It is required to prove that: $G/N$ is also solvable.

The solvability of $G$ means that $\exists$ a normal chain:

$$\{1\} = G_0 \subseteq G_1 \subseteq ... \subseteq G_{n-1} \subseteq G_n = G$$

That's, for each $0\le i \le n-1$, $G_i \unlhd G_{i+1}$ and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian.

**Work:**

After some trial and error, I decided that the best candidate chain would be:

$$N\{1\}/N \subseteq NG_1/N \subseteq ... \subseteq NG_{n-1}/N \subseteq G/N$$

Where $NK:= \{nk, n\in N, k \in K\}$.

Each one of these is well-defined: for each $i$, we have $N \unlhd G$ and $G_i \le G$ $\implies NG_i \le G$, moreover $N \subseteq NG_i$. Thus, $N \unlhd NG_i$.

Now we need to:

**1)** Prove that for each $i$, we have $NG_i/N \unlhd NG_{i+1}/N$.

Let $xN \in NG_i/N$ and $yN \in NG_{i+1}/N$ ($x \in NG_i$, $y \in NG_{i+1}$). We must prove that: $(yN)(xN)(yN)^{-1} \in NG_i/N$, i.e.: $(yxy^{-1})N \in NG_i/N$; i.e. $yxy^{-1} \in NG_i$

Thus, what we actually need to prove is: $NG_i \unlhd NG_{i+1}$.

For $ng \in NG_{i+1}$, we have:

$$(ng)NG_i (ng)^{-1} = ngNG_i g^{-1}n^{-1} = nNgG_i g^{-1}n^{-1} = NG_in^{-1} = G_i Nn^{-1} = G_i N = NG_i$$

And the result follows.

**2)** Prove that for each $i$, $(NG_{i+1}/N)/(NG_i/N)$ is abelian, which is equivalent to showing that $NG_{i+1}/NG_i$ is abelian.

I do not see how this might be done.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homomorphism $G_{i+1}/G_i\to NG_{i+1}/NG_i$, $gG_i\mapsto gNG_i$ is onto.